# How to handle unknown urls in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ok so my problem is that I´m not in control of the links fully (comes from a cms).

We have 3 possible types, category, product and cms, so we dont really know if the url "/gear" is a cms or category page.

How can I solve this issue?

I would like to use parent/child states like

```
home
home.category
home.category.product
home.cms
```

Current solution is that we have a route state that matches on anything /{url} and then we resolve the type and have a switch in our templateProvider.

It works but my gut feeling is that we should do it some other way and that we might miss out on standard parent/child features.

Any ideas are welcome! :)

Note: we are using version 1.0.0-beta.3 and routing to components

Comment: You could have a state that matches on anything, resolves the type, and then redirect to a specific route dedicated to that type.

Comment: You can have nested view to handle this

Comment: @JBNizet how would I do the redirect to the correct state?

Comment: Using $state.go().

Comment: I think I should be able to use redirectTo: but I cant access the resolved data :/

Comment: $urlRouterProvider.otherwisw() would do.